# trying to get the both card and cash members

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

Hi  I have done like this for getting  members details for  payment method type cash

```
       SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode, 
            members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob,30*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod/DateDiff(memberToMship_EndDate, memberToMship_StartDate) As monthly_amount, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name,
            membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate, IF(mshipOption_Period='year', TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
            TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate ) ) *memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total
          FROM members LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id,
          LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id,
          LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id,
          LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id,
          WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Cash'
          AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'
          AND (mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2' 
            OR mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = '3' 
            OR mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6')"
```

and another query like this for getting  members details with payment method  type card

```
                               SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode,
          members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob,
          30*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod/DateDiff(memberToMship_EndDate, memberToMship_StartDate) As monthly_amount, 
          mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name,
          membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate,
          IF(mshipOption_Period='year', TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
          TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate ) ) *memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total
        FROM members LEFT JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
        LEFT JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
        LEFT JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
        LEFT JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
        WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card'
        AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'
        AND (mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2' OR  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = '3' 
            OR mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6')"
```

but i want the member details those who have payment methods are  "cash and card" (both type members)

would any one help on this  query...

i am using MySQL

Many Thanks........

Modified Query

```
                       SELECT members.member_Id, members.member_Lastname, members.member_Firstname, members.member_PostCode,
          members.member_Reference,  members.member_Dob,30*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod/DateDiff(memberToMship_EndDate, memberToMship_StartDate) As monthly_amount, mshiptypes.mshipType_Name, mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Name,
          membertomships.memberToMship_EndDate,
          IF(mshipOption_Period='year', TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
          TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate,memberToMship_EndDate ) ) *memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod As Total
        FROM members
         INNER JOIN membertomships ON membertomships.member_Id = members.member_Id
        INNER JOIN mshipstatustypes ON mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = membertomships.mshipStatusType_Id
        INNER JOIN mshipoptions ON mshipoptions.mshipOption_Id = membertomships.mshipOption_Id
        INNER JOIN mshiptypes ON mshiptypes.mshipType_Id = mshipoptions.mshipType_Id
        WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod IN ('Card','Card','Cheque')
        AND members.member_Active LIKE 'y%'
        AND ( mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='2' OR  mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id = '3'
          OR mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id='6');
```

but it does not showing correct values..

Hi but one problem I have six Card members and 3 cash members individually it shows 6 and three but when combining(card and cash) it will shows only 4 .but it has to be shown (6+ 3) i dont know how it was like this would yoy pls tell any solution.

Comment: you gotta be kidding... **ALL** that crap is relevant to the question!? I didn't think so. Trim your code to the bear minimum, only *then* will someone be likely to answer your question

Comment: @Bohemain ya i have two payment types one is card and another one is cash i have done for individual but i want both also for putting into the list view

Comment: Suggestion: Use IN for mshipstatustypes.mshipStatusType_Id. Will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the only payment types are cash or card, you can leave out the where clause `membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod='Card'`

If there are other payment types, you can change it to

`membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod in ('Card', 'Cash')`

Comment: Hi but one problem I have six Card members and 3 cash members individually it shows 6 and three but when combining(card and cash) it will shows only 4 .but it has to be shown (6+ 3) i dont know how it was like this  would yoy pls tell any solution..

Comment: If you're running the modified query you've posted, it looks like there's a typo: WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod IN ('Card','Card','Cheque')
 should probably be WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod IN ('Card','Cash','Cheque')

Answer (score 1):

Use OR or IN

```
WHERE membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod IN ('Card','Cash')

WHERE (membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod ='Card' OR membertomships.memberToMship_PayMethod ='Cash')
```

Comment: Hi but one problem I have six Card members and 3 cash members individually it shows 6 and three but when combining(card and cash) it will shows only 4 .but it has to be shown (6+ 3) i dont know how it was like this  would yoy pls tell any solution